Why is CMake's relationship to FLTK install fragile?
Working on a Mac, I have a directory at /Users/ken/vsc/catch containing my project. It builds. Then I copied the full contents of that directory to /Users/ken/prog24/Catchwater. It doesn't build. The compiler can't find #include <FL/Fl.H>, and cmake find_package(FLTK REQUIRED) is not finding the package.  I observe that this header file exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fltk/1.3.9/include/FL but not in any path under /opt/homebrew/include.  Does this demonstrate a faulty installation by homebrew?
After reading a little more documentation, I went on a hunt for files named FindFLTK.cmake . I found two:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindFLTK.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindFLTK.cmake
diff shows them to be identical. There are actually two more instances of FindFLTK.cmake, buried deep in the app bundle of the Matlab application. Surely CMake is smart enough not to look in there, right?
Looking for any insights on how to diagnose this. And curious: /usr/local/Cellar is an unexpected path given what I have seen of homebrew. Does this look like an outdated install that needs to be wiped out?
Cmake version 3.29.4,
MacOS 14.2.1
Here’s CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Catchwater)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  "/opt/homebrew")
find_package(FLTK REQUIRED)
include_directories(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} .  ./FromGLOW ./Pipeworks ./fluidSim ./common /opt/homebrew/include)
link_directories(${FLTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_library(GLUT GLUT)
if (NOT GLUT)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GLUT is missing")
endif() 

message(STATUS FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS=${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Catchwater 
    Pipeworks/main.cpp Pipeworks/Catchwater.cpp Pipeworks/Flow.cpp Pipeworks/PipeType.cpp 
    Pipeworks/Text.cpp Pipeworks/fltkbasicgl.cpp Pipeworks/Spherical.cpp
    fluidSim/fluidSolver.cpp fluidSim/ fluidSim/particle.cpp fluidSim/sceneGrid.cpp 
    fluidSim/surface.cpp  fluidSim/triBoxOverlap.cpp  
    common/Tools.cpp common/V3.cpp common/quat.cpp common/Matrix.cpp common/mat16fv.cpp 
    common/vec3fv.cpp common/vec4fv.cpp fromGLOW/glowVectorAlgebra.cpp )

add_compile_definitions(GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)
target_compile_options(Catchwater PRIVATE -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-writable-strings -Wno-return-type -Wno-parentheses)
target_compile_features(Catchwater PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_link_libraries(Catchwater ${FLTK_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT})

The cmake output (Running under Cmake Tools extension of VSCode):
[main] Configuring project: Catchwater 
[proc] Executing command: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -S/Users/ken/prog24/Catchwater -B/Users/ken/prog24/Catchwater/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS=
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.2s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/ken/prog24/Catchwater/build


You can run cmake with --trace to get insight into what it's doing. from a quick look it seems that FindFLTK.cmake looks for FLTKConfig.cmake first

"The compiler can't find #include <FL/Fl.H>, and cmake find_package(FLTK REQUIRED) is not finding the package." - These problems cannot be observed at the same time. Failed find_package with REQUIRED keyword means failed configuration. And with failed configuration it is impossible to run building of the project. You have provided many details about your environment, but forgot to show the exact error message emitted by find_package.

Did you clean the cmake cache after moving the folder?

@AlanBirtles, yes I did.

@Tsyvarev, I have been perplexed about this very thing.The message line prints FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS= with nothing after it and yet there is no error message coming from the configure. That would seem like failure, I don't know what to make of it. I am editing the question to include the output of cmake.

Delete the whole build directory and start over. Copy the output of the first run after deletion here. Only then we can be sure to have no side effects.

FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS is not listed as output variable for FindFLTK.cmake CMake module. You probably wanted to use FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR variable instead.

@Joymaker: Short answer to your question: it is not.
The problem with your description (I take it literally) is that you copied the (CMake) build directory after building your project. This does not work because CMake stores explicit paths in its cache and these paths are very likely no longer correct if you copy the build directory. If you copy the project to another directory you need to clean the build folder or at least the cache file and start a full new configuration process. This is a documented CMake property and has nothing to do with FLTK.
If, OTOH, you want to copy the build products (libs and header files) to another location, then you need to use CMake's install command, i.e. either cmake --install, make install, ninja install, etc., depending on what build tools you are using. The cmake --install command can be used for all build systems.
Regarding FLTK: as others wrote, FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS is not the correct variable if you are using find_package(FLTK REQUIRED) as given in your post (use FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR instead).
Current FLTK (1.3.x and later) docs recommend to use find_package(FLTK CONFIG REQUIRED) instead. Note the CONFIG keyword. This requires that the FLTK library you (want to) use has been built using CMake itself - see further advice in FLTK's README.CMake.txt. However, I'm not sure if homebrew's FLTK provides a FLTKConfig.cmake file. If it doesn't I recommend to build FLTK yourself with CMake.
